# Can I create an NSColor with code so that it can change according to dark mode or light mode?

Tags: swift, cocoa, nscolor

[image]
I can create such a color in Xcode asset management, of course it takes more than 10.13 to be applied.

I'm currently adding theme functionality to my app, and I think it might be helpful to code an NSColor object that automatically adapts to bright or dark modes.

I don't know if it can be achieved. If it can't be achieved, I don't know if there is any more information about the subject that can be given to me.

Answer (score 0):

The standard system colors (**labelColor**, **controlColor**, etc) are automatically adjusted for dark mode, otherwise you will need to provide your own colors and methods to determine the setting (or use **NSAppearance**) - see [Supporting Dark Mode in Your Interface](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/appkit/supporting_dark_mode_in_your_interface).